# JCR/Sling - Does it make sense for a Node Property to contain a JSON value, OR should the corresponding subnodes be created?

Tags: aem, sling, jcr

I am developing a fairly simple AEM component, but I'm stuck understanding the best practice.

For example, let's say I want to store a set of `Link` objects, each of which contains a **href** & **title** properties.

This can be stored in 2 ways:

**[1]** Each link as a separate node:

```
 component
    ├── link_1
    │   ├── .href  = "#1"
    │   └── .title = "T1"
    └── link_2
        ├── .href  = "#2" 
        └── .title = "T2"
```

**[2]** As a JSONArray property beneath `component`:

```
 component
    └── .links = [{"href":"#1", "title":"T1"}, {"href":"#2", "title":"T2"}]
```

---

After writing this out, I think I answered my own question...

Even though Option **[2]** is appealing for component development, it seems redundant when JCR/Sling data modeling already provides that hierarchy.

---

- Am I understanding this correctly?
- I know it is possible to export a `Resource`as JSON, but is it possible to import/create a `SyntheticResource` from JSON?

  - If not that, when would one use `SyntheticResource`
- Would I be better off storing the `link` nodes beneath a separate a distinct parent node for organization?

`component
        └── links
            ├── link_1
            │   ├── .href  = "#1"
            │   └── .title = "T1"
            └── link_2
                ├── .href  = "#2" 
                └── .title = "T2"`

Comment: I'd say, it depends on your user-case. But since this is a component, I assume you are using a composite multi-field to author those values? I wrote an article about that here: https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/08/24/using-sling-models-with-nested-composite-mulitifields-in-aem-6-3/.
I generally prefer structures that can be easily adapted to a sling model, so I'd go the JCR route. Although, you could get away with using JSON string, but it's just ugly to look at (again personal preference )

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend creating nodes in jcr. Storing as json may prohibit you from using (or complicate the use of) a number of jcr/aem provided functionalities e.g. indexing, searching, event handling, access control etc.

Although your example is simple and some of the above listed things may not apply, it would create problems if someone were to store more complex data as json.

Comment: agreed. my vote will be JCR way just to keep simple and avoid complexity.